# Safer/Less intense way doing it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

As I'm trying to paint some line on a canvas and show number(s) to people I am using such code for it.

```
timer = setInterval(function(){
        x += 0.1;
        io.sockets.emit('message', {
            type: 'graph',
            x: x
        });
}, 100);
```

I also have an `if` variable there if that X goes over example 5 then it will stop it and same thing will start again in 5 seconds. Is there a better way of doing such thing?

Comment: The code you have showed has nothing to do with either `paint some line on a canvas` nor `show number(s) to people`. Not sure I know what the question actually is.

Comment: It's completely not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: How is it not clear? What is my alternative doing the same thing? As using a setInterval seems to be really intense.

Comment: There is painting on canvas, socket emits the data to the user jQuery and there happens the painting. It's the backend code which sends it there.